# KeyboardAvoidingView Issue With TextInput and Animated.API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-animated

I designed a page and I have a Flatlist and I have pickers, slider and text input in this page. I also used Animated View in this page and I have an issue with KeyboardAvoidingView.

The design looks like this when the page is first rendered:[First Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRUHb.png)

When user click "Add" Icon the page looks like this:
[Animation Triggered and View Flex Grow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjfsh.png)

And here is my main issue. When user click the TextInput for type something. This page looks like this:
[TextInput Focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiM0p.png)

You can also see my render code in this photo.[JSX Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzNni.png)

I tried placing "keyboardavoidingview" in different places but my problem was not solved. How can I solve this?

P.S: The animation value based on "flex" property. The view has "0.5" flex value on first start and When the button is clicked, it takes the value "1".

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code inside

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

And give it a style like this

```
 flex: 1,
 behavior="padding"
```

Kolay gelsin :)

Comment: After adding this when I click on Textinput the keyboard appears for a second and then disappears. I think the main problem is that flex values and flatlist do not allow this behavior. Teşekkürler :)

Comment: Yeah maybe. Just try removing the flex value